# MySQL indexing to efficiently query table join with many to many relationship

Tags: mysql, indexing

I've been struggling to create the correct index to improve performance for a specific query we run on our database, I hope one of you can help point me in the right direction.

I have 2 tables as per below. I have a query to find all employees of companies that belong to a specific category with first_name like "Be%" for example. I've tried creating a multiple index on `category_id, company_id` but this hasn't helped. What should be the correct way to index my tables to achieve better performance for this query? Thank you in advance.

```
SELECT 
  e.* 
FROM employee e
INNER JOIN company c ON e.company_id = c.company_id
WHERE c.category_id = 6
AND e.first_name LIKE "Be%"
GROUP BY e.employee_id
```

> TABLE company

```
| company_id | category_id |
+------------+-------------+
| ...        | ...         |
+------------+-------------+
| 47         | 6           |
+------------+-------------+
| ..         | ...         |
+------------+-------------+
| 252        | 6           |
+------------+-------------+
```

> TABLE employee

```
| employee_id | company_id | first_name | ... |
+-------------+------------+------------+-----+
| 2582250     | 47         | Ben        | ... |
+-------------+------------+------------+-----+
| 3447890     | 252        | Ryan       | ... |
+-------------+------------+------------+-----+
| 7125966     | 252        | Beth       | ... |
+-------------+------------+------------+-----+
| ...         | ...        | ...        | ... |
+-------------+------------+------------+-----+
```

> CREATE TABLES below and [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3ffeb/1).

```
CREATE TABLE company (
  `company_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  `category_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE employee (
  `employee_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  `company_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `first_name` VARCHAR(255)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Comment: I suggest ... and ..., and ... also. Alternatively, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @Strawberry thanks I've added as requested. Unfortunately this only becomes a problem with a couple millions rows which isn't feasible in sqlfiddle.

Comment: Ok. I should have added...

Comment: Problems about query performance ALWAYS require SHOW CREATE TABLE statements for all relevant tables, as well as the EXPLAIN for the given query

Comment: Did you mean `company_id` when you wrote `country_id`?

Answer (score 1):

You *must* have indexes in many:many tables.  Follow the advice outlined [*here*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table).

```
WHERE c.category_id = 6
  AND e.first_name LIKE "Be%"
```

needs

```
c: INDEX(category_id, company_id) -- which will be called for in the link above
e: INDEX(first_name, employee_id)
```

The Optimizer will either start with `c`, then reach into `e`.  Or vice versa.  I am providing you the optimal indexes for either direction.